# Control how long iPhone startup/launch image remains on screen for HTML5 app?

Tags: jquery, ios, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

Is it possible to control how long the startup image (like the one below) for an HTML5 app remains on the screen? Specifically, we want to persist the startup image until all images for our HTML5 app have loaded.

Is there a way to do this?

We're building for mobile Safari and using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2.

```
<!-- iPhone 3 and 4 Non-Retina -->
<link rel='apple-touch-startup-image' media='(device-width: 320px)' href='/images/x/apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png'>
```

Comment: Startup image means launch image?? If yes, then why not show a viewController with launch image or loading screen until you finished loading your images. You cannot set the time limit to your launch image. And you are going to load images in webview. So your launch image wont wait till you finish loading images. Better to show another viewController

Comment: This is for an HTML5 app, not a native app.

Comment: Means you can't even add a `UIView` in your `UIWindow` and show in top of all views till you finish loading images. I doubt that.

Comment: Correct, this is a web app, not a native app.

Comment: Actually, the startup image *should* stay visible until `$(window).load()` is triggered by the browser. That being said, there's not a way to keep the launch image up per the default Apple Startup Image. You would have to use jQuery (or something client-side) to display the image and then remove it on `$(window).load()`. I would recommend firing a JQM dialog that alerts the user that the page is still loading. There are of course other ways to display the image, but this keeps within JQM standards: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/dialog/

Comment: what if we looped window.load for a few seconds? is the startup image supposed to get dismissed on trigger or completion of window.load?